# matlab floating number accuracy 2^(-45)

Tags: matlab, floating-point, binary, rounding, precision

I have two pair of numbers `(155.11 , 155.35)` and `(154.95 , 155.19)`, their differences are both 0.24. In matlab if I calculate 
`(155.11 - 155.35) - (154.95 - 155.19)`, the matlab will output `2.8422e-14`,which is `2^(-45)`. I know this is an issue of machine resolution on floating number representation, but was curious on the detail, why it is this value? what is special on 45?

Comment: it comes from the data type, i.e. whether it's a 16-bit or 32-bit number. eps is the smallest possible precision given the bit length.

Comment: class(155.11 - 155.35) is double, which should have a higher precision 52 rather 45?

Comment: @BlueRineS, `esp` is the floating-point **relative** accuracy.

Comment: @obchardon relative w.r.t. what?

Comment: All floating point number cannot be reached, so `esp('single')` is the distance between `1` and the next larger single precision number. So in this case it's relative to `1`.

Comment: @obchardon so the next reachable 32 bit float that can be represented after '1' is (1+2.8422e-14) ?

Comment: @BlueRineS: According to the docs, "eps('single') is the same as eps(single(1.0))". That means that the first representable 32-bit float number larger than 1.0 is `1.0+eps(single(1.0))`, which is `1.0+1.1921e-07`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eps(155.11)` is 2.8422e-14. The rounding already happens in the original numbers you enter.

Comment: I see. it is about log2(eps) + log2(155.11)

Comment: And in this specific case (operands in same binade) all the subtract operations are exact (the only inexact is indeed the conversion decimal->binary floating point).

Comment: @ahala it's `log2(abs(eps))`, or `floor(log2(abs(155.11))) - 52 % 52=floating precision - 1`